# Switch from 3.3V to 24V Raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, mosfet, raspberry-pi

I want to convert the Raspberry Pi's 3.3V output to 24V as this is what the I/O uses on the Universal Robot arm, UR5. The 24V is supplied by the UR5 and so I thought that a simple NPN transistor would suffice, but no. As the V_B is only 3.3V it will never be greater than the V_C which is 24V. so I would never be able to drive it into saturation, am I right?

I've been looking around for solutions and saw a lot of clues bot no solutions that applied directly to my problem.

Comment: You would probably find it easier to use the Ethernet interface...

Answer (score 1):

Your post/tags are confusing. If you want to use an NPN BJT transistor you should remove the MOSFET tag. If you want to use a MOSFET you should correct the terminology in the post. However, either way the effect is the same.

As Vbe or Vgs goes up and the transistor starts turning on more and more, it will draw more current into the collector/drain. The voltage drop from this current flowing through whatever load resistor you are using will cause the voltage at the collector/drain to drop. Eventually it will drop so far that the collector/drain is at a lower voltage than the base/gate. At this point the BJT will be saturated, or a MOSFET will be in triode mode, which are the appropriate modes for use as a switching device.

Both other answers seem to forget that saturation for a MOSFET is the equivalent of forward active mode for a BJT, and is not what you want for switching.

Answer (score 0):

An N-Channel MOSFET will start to saturate at V_gth, which isn't necessarily that high. A cursory glance on digikey turns up:

http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3404A.pdf

[image]

The idea of an N-channel is that you need the gate to be a little above source to start conducting. In a P-channel, you'd need to drive from source to drain, the full swing.

note - I'm not recommending that particular mosfet. That's just the first thing that came up searching for a logic-level n-mosfet.

Comment: The question references voltages on the terminal of a bipolar junction transistor, not those of an FET.

Comment: @ChrisStratton while he does use terminology consistent with a BJT, the question is tagged with "mosfet." Given that, and the question itself, it seems to be that he isn't sure which to use, or the differences between them. Especially considering that there isn't an explicit "can't use a MOSFET" requirement, and he's just looking at a way to solve the specific issue, an N-Channel MOSFET seems appropraite.

Comment: There's no supply available to make Vbe (or Vgs if you want a FET) positive if an NPN (or N FET) is used. Sure, you could synthesize one like the other guy was going on about. But the logical solution is to use a PNP (or if you must have a FET P-channel) device driven in turn by an NPN.  **Remember this isn't power electronics, it's a <15mA Logic Signal** so think logic structure with higher voltage rating, and forget about the advantages of N channel vs. P channel carriers in power settings. Actually, forget the whole thing, both devices have Ethernet ports, all he needs is a cable.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Missed the fact that he's asking for level shifting, not just on/off.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for all your replies!

I researched a bit more and decided that a transistor and everything similar were going to be to dangerous. So I decided to use an octocoupler, more specifically a K827P, so that the Raspberry Pi is totally isolated from the 24V.

[image]

As seen in the diagram the microcomputer is protected, and a resistor is added to minimize the current flow. The diode needs 60mA to run and with the 3.3V power supply from the Raspberry Pi that gives a resistor value of 3.3V/0.06A = 55 ohm. On the output side (NB! This is not illustrated) there's added a pull down resistor which is computed to be 480 ohm. This as the transistor needs 50mA and the supply is 24V (24V/0.05A = 480 ohm).

Hope this helps others.

Comment: This is the start of a decent idea, but you are misreading the K827P data sheet - 60mA is the absolute maximum current rating.  It actually needs less than 10mA, which is a good thing as 60mA is too much for the pi.  If you *were* driving a higher current LED, you might want to set things up for low-side drive where the chip drives the negative lead and the positive is connected to the supply, because the low side drivers of a push/pull output are typically stronger than the high side ones due to the greater mobility of electron carriers.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be around 10V higher than V(gth) (Usually; check graphs of Vgs first) for maximum switching speed, otherwise you will spend a massive amount of time trying to 'turn on' the FET, or alternatively the next signal might overlap the previous, meaning you garble the I/O data.

On top of that, you have to make sure you have enough current to 'pump' the FET gate full of charge otherwise you will end up with a really hot, really slow moving arm.

Just use a FET driver, send it an input signal through a 5V (or whatever it requires) comparator from the 3.3V Raspberry Pi output, then hook up the 24V line to your switching system.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCd8oz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will drive a single FET into saturation from 24V whenever you pulse the signal.

Comment: The poster is contemplating a bipolar junction transistor, not an FET.

Comment: No, he's contemplating a MOSFET.

Comment: No, an NPN is a **biploar junction** transistor.  And the reference are to the leads of bipolar devices, not FET's.

Comment: "transistors" "mosfet" "raspberry-pi"

Comment: The question asked is specifically about the voltages on a base and a collector.  These are terminals found on junction transistors **not on FET's**.

Comment: Tell me how one saturates an IGBT with voltage relative to ground. You don't. He's talking about a FET, that's why he said his 3.3V signal was not going to drive the thing higher than 24V on the rail. Who the hell cares what he said, address what he meant.

Comment: Not an IGBT either.  This is a high voltage logic signal (less than 15 milliamps according to the manual), not power.

Comment: According to the manual the internal 24V supply can push 2A (Section 4.3, I-20) , so I'm assuming that drives some of the servomotors for it too. In either case, a MOSFET is probably going to be better for rapid signals, if it's doing any quick or precise adjustments. 15mA is the spec for the actual input terminals themselves.

Comment: The question concerns driving the Digital I/O.  The manual specifies 15ma max current - obviously the servo amps are downstream.

Comment: That's the maximum current rating of the digital input pin at 11-30V for pins 'EIx/SIx/CIx/DIx'. The maximum rating for the internal 24V power supply is 2A. Is this clear to you? He can draw 2A from his robot, he can input signals up to 15mA. He wants to use the 24V supply to push signals at <15mA into the inputs. The question of the NPN MOSFET refers to the 2A power supply. And it refers to the 2A power supply because you can't pull current from an input pin and then stick it back in the input pin. Just read the specs.

Comment: "He wants to use the 24V supply to push signals at <15mA into the inputs." indeed - and do you really think your answer is the best way to do that?  I think you answered a different question than the one that was asked - which is a relatively innocent mistake, but vehemently defending it for the next couple hours is pointless.

Comment: That's the maximum current rating of the digital input pin at 11-30V for pins 'EIx/SIx/CIx/DIx'. The maximum rating for the internal 24V power supply is 2A. Is this clear to you? He can draw 2A from his robot, he can input signals up to 15mA. He wants to use the 24V supply to push signals at <15mA into the inputs. The question of the NPN MOSFET refers to the 2A power supply. And it refers to the 2A power supply because you can't pull current from an input pin and then stick it back in the input pin. Just read the specs.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely think my answer is the best way to do it. It's a safe option that isolates his control circuitry from the robot's power circuitry, while still allowing him to draw from it's internal supply. The ONLY thing missing is a current limiting resistor of 1600R. **EDIT: Nice deleted comment, bro; "Do you honestly think your circuit is the best way to do this?"**

Comment: Nothing was deleted.

Comment: Until about halfway through this conversation, you didn't know a fourth of what was going on in his question. My answer is correct, exhaustive, and most of all, safe for him; replace the load with a current limiting resistor going out to the input terminal and suddenly you will be able to talk to the 24V input without a separate 24V supply. 5V is from the Raspberry-Pi 5V pin. Should be around 350/400mA safe draw.

Comment: If you care so much about it, criticize and provide an alternative. Don't nitpick, proceed to get it wrong, and then continue pressing on trivialities for ten comments into the answer. You are just confusing the people who come down here.